# Sleep in Mac OSX Snow Leopard - Wake up in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, sleep, boot-camp

I've got a MacBook PRO with Snow Leopard and have just installed Windows 7 via Boot Camp. I've installed the Windows Support and updated to the latest Boot Camp version (3.2). This is the issues I have (btw, I'm using SmartSleep v3.08, can be bought in AppStore):

- When going to sleep mode (I've set sleep to be hibernation) in Mac OSX it will wake up in Windows 7.
- When powering-on the computer, it starts in Windows 7 if I don't push the alt-button and choose Mac OSX, I want it to be the other way around!

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Change the default boot partition in the Startup Disk control panel.** You currently have the Windows 7 partition selected, so unless otherwise instructed, the computer will boot up in Windows 7. You need to select the Mac OS X partition as the default.

Since you've installed the Boot Camp Utilities in Windows, you can do this from either operating system.